# Enable Device Screen Rotation Landscape or Potrait, only for Tablet Device by Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, tablet, landscape

I would like to enable my application screen to landscape or portrait only for tablets. Still on Portrait for smartphone The application was developed by Flutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set portrait with [SystemChrome](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setSystemUIOverlayStyle.html)

```
final data = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance!.window);
if(data.size.shortestSide > 600) { // check if its bigger
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
} else { // otherwise will be ..
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]);
}
```

Play with digit to get the best

Comment: For the landscape, i added the DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft and Right, thank you for helping

Comment: Where is the 600 comes from?

Comment: The 600 is for device pixel, you need to change it due to device and make logic, e.g under 600 is mobile

Comment: i think it is not from pixel, because i tried with Nexus 5 with 1080 pixel, the landscape that i configured didn't run. So, maybe the 600 is from width of screen

Comment: My bad, yeah its for device width

Answer (score 3):

check device is tablet

```
class DeviceUtil {
  static String get _getDeviceType {
    final data = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window);
    return data.size.shortestSide < 550 ? 'phone' : 'tablet';
  }

  static bool get isTablet {
    return _getDeviceType == 'tablet';
  }
}

DeviceUtil.isTablet; //true
```

use of this

```
  if(DeviceUtil.isTablet){
     //landscape-or-potrait
}else{
//landscape-or-potrait
}
```

Comment: Where is the 550 comes from?

Comment: standard aspect ratio for device